# refresh excel spreadsheet without using win32com

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, win32com

I have a .xlsx file that I am writing data into. This data is then used by other cells/equations to generate other values, tables, etc.

The problem is, after I write data to the xlsx file, when I read it back in the data is empty.

I realized I had to open / refresh / close the excel file before reading it back in and it works.

I've done this using this function:

```
import win32com.client
import os
def update_excel(file):
    excel = win32com.client.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(file))
    wb.RefreshAll()
    wb.Save()
    wb.Close()
    excel.Quit()
```

which works fine.

The problem is now that I've gone to a machine that doesn't have excel installed and this is no longer and option.

After some digging, I realized `openpyxl` cannot do this (I think), neither can `pywin32`, `koogra`, or other solutions that I've seen. At least to my knowledge.

My question is:

How can I refresh the xlsx file without having excel installed? Perhaps some kind of libre/open office approach?

Comment: Your explanation doesn't make sense.  Opening Excel should have no effect at all on the availability of data.  You should show us the original code that didn't work -- let's make THAT work, so you don't depend on Excel at all.

Comment: You can run open office in headless mode.

Comment: +1 to question. This is valid question and bugging me too for some time. All the similar SO threads shows refresh with win32com only or using macro.